# Octave : strange error when using ones

Tags: matrix, octave

I don't know why I have this strange error when using Octave on Windows 7 64 bit :

when I use `ones(100:100)` to declare a matrix 100x100. No problem. But when I use : `ones(10:100)` I will have error :

> memory exhausted or requested size too large

And if I use `ones(10:15)` I must wait for long time (about 30 seconds) to have answer.

Please explain for me this error.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong. To create an m x n matrix it should be:

```
ones(m,n)
```

e.g.

```
ones(100,100)
```

or

```
ones(10,15)
```

Comment: but I don't know, for example, when I type: ones(3:4), it will create a matrix 3x4. Can you explain please. thanks :)

Comment: when you type 3:4, you get [3,4] so ones (3:4) generates a 3x4 matrix. However, [2:4] is [2, 3, 4], it generates a 2x3x4 matrix. Can you guess why (10:100) was using too memory? It was doing a 2x3x4x5x...x100 matrix. It's a huge thing. a 100:100 matrix returns only 100 so you get a 100x100 matrix. The : is working as the range operator.